# How to show categories which are not included in navigation menu in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, filter, categories

How to show categories which are not included in navigation menu in Magento?

```
<?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
    <li>
      <a <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0){ ?>
      href='#' 
      <?php }else {  ?>
      href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>"    

      <?php }?>

     <?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>

    </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 0)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position

foreach ($collection as $category) {
//do something with $category
}
```

Comment: Let me add a filter to get categories within a specific parent category.

   `->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId)); `

Answer (score 3):

In category collection you have to check if it is included in navigation menu or not

```
if (!$_category->getIncludeInMenu()) {
    // your code here
}
```

Here is the code to get it working -

```
foreach($_subcategories->getData() as $category) {
    $subcatid = $category['entity_id'];
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcatid);
    if (!$_cat->getIncludeInMenu()) {
        echo $_cat->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got: Call to undefined method Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection::getData()